# How to make the following regex match and replace unclosed double quotes?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

The following code replace straight double quotes with curly double quotes:

```js
 const input = `"Line 1"

"Line 2

"Line 3"

Line 4`
 
const output = input.replace(/\"(.*?)(\")/g, '&ldquo;$1&rdquo;')
 
console.log(output)
```

There's a problem, though. Sometimes a line doesn't have a closing double quote (which indicates that the quotes continues on the line below). So the opening double quote won't be replaced:

```
`&ldquo;Line 1$1&rdquo;

"Line 2

&ldquo;Line 3$1&rdquo;

Line 4`
```

How to modify the regex so it also replaces opening double quotes that aren't followed by a closing double quote?

Desired output:

```
`&ldquo;Line 1$1&rdquo;

&ldquo;Line 2

&ldquo;Line 3$1&rdquo;

Line 4`
```

Comment: Try `replace(/^"([^"\n\r]*)"?$/gm, "&ldquo;$1&rdquo;")`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That worked perfectly. Do you want to post that comment as an answer with a little explanation?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew How come `&rdquo` isn't being added after `Line 2` (which is okay, since it's what I want)? How come the regex knows not to add it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
.replace(/^"([^"\n\r]*)"?$/gm, "&ldquo;$1&rdquo;")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pwA5Mz/1). The regex matches all non-overlapping occurrences (`g`), while matching start of lines with `^` and end of lines with `$` (due to `m`) and means

- `^` - start of a line
- `"` - a double quotation mark
- `([^"\n\r]*)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than `"`, CR and LF
- `"?` - an optional `"` char
- `$` - end of any line.

See the JavaScript demo:

```js
 const input = `"Line 1"

"Line 2

"Line 3"

Line 4`
 
const output = input.replace(/^"([^"\n\r]*)"?$/gm, '&ldquo;$1&rdquo;')
 
console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go in 2 successive `replace()`, if it's ok:

- one for caching the `"...'"` form
- another for catching the remaining `"...`

```js
const output = input
    .replace(/\"(.*?)(\")/g, '&ldquo;$1&rdquo;')
    .replace(/\"(.*)/g, '&ldquo;$1&rdquo;')
```

But I didn't understand if you wanted to match multilines results in an unique final string, or just add quotes to the end of each line

Answer (score 1):

1. List item

```js
const input = `"Line 1"

    "Line 2

    "Line 3"

    Line 4`
     
      const output = input.replace(/"([^"/]*)"/g, '&ldquo;$1&rdquo;')

     
    console.log(output)
```

Comment: Thanks, but there's a closing right quote after Line 2.